# How can i automate testing for my database driven .Net application

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I have spent the last few days learning about Unit testing. However I am looking to automate some testing for my .Net web application and am having trouble trying to workout exactly how I would go about this.

My web application is basically a quiz that retrieves articles, questions and multi choice answers from a SQL and then displays these to the user.

The web application then records the selected answers and saves them in the database.

From what I have read about Unit testing is that you test a single component at a time, however I don't have any complex algorithms as the app just checks if the user got the answers right or wrong.

What kind of automated tests can I add to my application (if any)?